# With join what must be the fields in order to take all the values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

```
 $query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa');
 $query->leftJoin('malgona', 'm', 'm.wid = wa.wid')
       ->fields('m');
```

If I put in fields `m` I only take the values of `m` and if I put `wa` I only take the values of `wa`. What must be the fields value in order to take the join (with values from both tables)?

Comment: Have you tried something like `->fields('m, wa')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the fields method several times:

```
 $query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa');
 $query->leftJoin('malgona', 'm', 'm.wid = wa.wid')
    ->fields('wa')
    ->fields('m');
```

It is probably better if you also define the columns for the tables as using this generic fields without column definitions will result in name collision [(see Drupal:Fields)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1848352) if you have same named columns in the tables:

```
 $query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa');
 $query->leftJoin('malgona', 'm', 'm.wid = wa.wid')
    ->fields('wa', array('wa_id', 'wa_field1', 'wa_field2'))
    ->fields('m', array('m_id', 'm_field1', 'm_field2'));
```